# How to Enable Linting for Braceless SASS with Svelte-VSCcode

Tags: visual-studio-code, sass, svelte

Currently, I have VSCode properly linting **SCSS** for Svelte using the following setup; however, it does not work for braceless **SASS**. `<style type="text/sass">` will process correctly, however VSCode will repeatedly highlight errors requesting braces.

How should I update the follow to allow linting for braceless SASS?

```
\\ svelte.config.js

const sveltePreprocess = require('svelte-preprocess');

module.exports = {
    preprocess: sveltePreprocess()
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately SASS is not supported. The Svelta Beta extension only supports syntax  for Less/CSS/SCSS. This is the case because the html language service that the work is delegated to (https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-html-languageservice) does not support SASS.